# How is $F=ma$ a differential equation? (Confirmation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Just wanna make sure I have this right. The derivative of position is velocity, and  the derivative of velocity is acceleration

so if $$F = ma$$

where 
$$a=\frac{d}{dx} v(t)\\
v(t)=\frac{d}{dx} s(t)$$  where $s(t)$ is the position in time.

This means that $$a = s''(t)$$
which means $$F = ms''(t)$$

and its an ordinary differential equation because it contains ordinary derivatives and it doesn't have the weird partial derivative symbol anywhere?

Is everything above right? Thanks.

Comment: shouldn't it be  $$ F=m\frac{d^2s(t)}{dt^2}$$

Comment: Note that $a(t)=\frac{d}{d\color{red}t} v(t), v(t)=\frac{d}{d\color{red}t} s(t)$

Comment: @CaptXan Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Just expand a little on what everyone has already said: In general, assuming the mass $m$ and velocity $\mathbf{v}$ are functions of time only: 
$$ \mathbf{F}= \frac{d}{dt}\left(m\mathbf{v}\right) = m\frac{d \mathbf{v}}{dt}+ 
 \frac{dm}{dt}\mathbf{v}$$
The above results follows from the fact that force is the rate of change of momentum with time, and momentum is the product of mass and velocity.

Now, if the mass $m$ is constant, then $\mathbf{v} =\frac{d \mathbf{s}}{dt}$ and 
$$\mathbf{F}= m\frac{d \mathbf{v}}{dt} = m\mathbf{a}$$
Finally (again assuming that $m$ is constant), if $\mathbf{s}$ is the displacement vector as a function of time, then $\mathbf{v} =\frac{d \mathbf{s}}{dt}$, which implies that 
$$\mathbf{F}= m\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d \mathbf{s}}{dt}\right) = m\left[\frac{d^2}{{dt}^2}\mathbf{s}(t)\right] = m\mathbf{a}$$

Comment: This is mathematically correct, but physically the force is only the derivative of the momentum if the mass is constant. Otherwise your general expression for the force won't be Galilean-invariant which can't be.

Comment: @LutzLehmann No, that is a common misconception about Newon's laws. They only (!) apply to systems with fixed mass. If you want to derive the rocket equation, you have to take into account the mass of the ejected particles as well, $F = \frac{dm}{dt}v + ma$ won't work. You can easily see that this "generalised force" is not Galilean invariant (apply a boost $x \mapsto vt$). See also [this answer on physics stack exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113677/force-as-change-in-momentum-vs-change-in-velocity/113686#113686).

Comment: I'm not sure that I accept the invariance argument, there should be no problem if all parts of the original system are kept in the calculus. But that the rocket calculation only works if the thrust vector aligns with the motion vector is understandable.

Comment: @LutzLehmann If force would depend on the frame of reference, then the acceleration of a particle would be dependant on the frame of reference - since mass doesn't transform when changing the frame of reference. Chaning acceleration wouldn't be weird in non-inertial frames, but in frames which result from Galilean-boosts this results in non-sensical physics. You can see this as a foreshadowing of special relativity where this general force law can be again considered as correct, at the cost of considering inertial mass to change with the frame of reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct, in the particular case of a mass-spring system we have $F=-ks$ and the differential equation becomes

$$m\ddot{s}+ks=0$$